# Derivative of a distance function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about a derivative of a distance function.

Let $D$ be a bounded and connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with Lipschitz boundary. We define the following distance function $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.
\begin{align}
F(x)=d(x,\partial D)\left(=\inf_{y \in \partial D}|x-y| \right)
\end{align}
Since this function is Lipschitz continuous, differentiable in a.e. sense (Rademacher's theorem).

**Question**

**I want to know the value of $\left|\nabla F \right|$.**

Since Lipschitz constant of $F$ is $1$, we can deduce $\left| \nabla F \right| \le 1$ a.e. Can we show 
\begin{align}
\left|\nabla F \right| \ge 1 \text{ a.e. or }\left| \nabla F \right| > 0 \text{ a.e. ?}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As You wrote, by the Radamecher theorem, You  have the existence  of $\nabla  F $ (the Fr{\'e}chet derivative) a. e. . The noneptiness of the metric projection mapping at each point of the space  is obvious (by the local compactness). Thus a simple calculation gives $\|\nabla F \|=1\|$ a.e. (calculate the directional derivative along the ray given by the point and its projection on the boundary)